# Delphi XE2 XML Data Binding Wizard bug when XSD contains IMPORTED xsd's

Tags: xml, delphi, data-binding, xsd, delphi-xe2

When the XSD contains other imported XSD's, the XML entries referring to the imported XSD's do not include namespace prefix.

This is start of the xsd with multiple imports:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:inv="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0"
xmlns:icls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0" 
xmlns:ecls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0" 
targetNamespace="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0"
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
version="1.0.3">
<xs:import namespace="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0" 
schemaLocation="incomeClassification-v1.0.3.xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0" 
schemaLocation="expensesClassification-v1.0.3.xsd"/>
```

An example XML produced looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--XML document created with Delphi XE2 by Three Plus Ltd-->
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0" 
xmlns:icls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0" 
xmlns:ecls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0">
<invoice>
<uid>1</uid>
<mark>240254</mark>
<issuer>
  <vatNumber>084110672</vatNumber>
  <country>GR</country>
  <branch>0</branch>
</issuer>
<counterpart>
  <vatNumber>052354924</vatNumber>
  <country>GR</country>
  <branch>0</branch>
  <address>
    <postalCode></postalCode>
    <city>ΑΓΙΑ ΒΑΡΒΑΡΑ</city>
  </address>
</counterpart>
<invoiceHeader>
  <series>Β</series>
  <aa>59</aa>
  <issueDate>2021-01-07</issueDate>
  <invoiceType>1.1</invoiceType>
  <currency>EUR</currency>
</invoiceHeader>
<paymentMethods>
  <paymentMethodDetails>
    <type>3</type>
    <amount>254.68</amount>
  </paymentMethodDetails>
</paymentMethods>
<invoiceDetails>
  <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
  <netValue>205.39</netValue>
  <vatCategory>1</vatCategory>
  <vatAmount>49.29</vatAmount>
  <incomeClassification>
    <classificationType>E3_561_001</classificationType>
    <classificationCategory>category1_1</classificationCategory>
    <amount>205.39</amount>
  </incomeClassification>
</invoiceDetails>
<invoiceSummary>
  <totalNetValue>205.39</totalNetValue>
  <totalVatAmount>49.29</totalVatAmount>
  <totalWithheldAmount>0.00</totalWithheldAmount>
  <totalFeesAmount>0.00</totalFeesAmount>
  <totalStampDutyAmount>0.00</totalStampDutyAmount>
  <totalOtherTaxesAmount>0.00</totalOtherTaxesAmount>
  <totalDeductionsAmount>0.00</totalDeductionsAmount>
  <totalGrossValue>254.68</totalGrossValue>
  <incomeClassification>
    <classificationType>E3_561_001</classificationType>
    <classificationCategory>category1_1</classificationCategory>
    <amount>205.39</amount>
  </incomeClassification>
</invoiceSummary>
</invoice>
</InvoicesDoc>
```

This XML does not pass validation as the IncomeClassification entries should include the prefix "icls" like below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--XML document created with Delphi XE2 by Three Plus Ltd-->
<InvoicesDoc xmlns="http://www.aade.gr/myDATA/invoice/v1.0" 
xmlns:icls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/incomeClassificaton/v1.0" 
xmlns:ecls="https://www.aade.gr/myDATA/expensesClassificaton/v1.0">
<invoice>
<uid>1</uid>
<mark>241108</mark>
<issuer>
  <vatNumber>084110672</vatNumber>
  <country>GR</country>
  <branch>0</branch>
</issuer>
<counterpart>
  <vatNumber>130197574</vatNumber>
  <country>GR</country>
  <branch>0</branch>
  <address>
    <postalCode>12135</postalCode>
    <city>ΠΕΡΙΣΤΕΡΙ</city>
  </address>
</counterpart>
<invoiceHeader>
  <series>Β</series>
  <aa>274</aa>
  <issueDate>2021-01-16</issueDate>
  <invoiceType>1.1</invoiceType>
  <currency>EUR</currency>
</invoiceHeader>
<paymentMethods>
  <paymentMethodDetails>
    <type>5</type>
    <amount>45.50</amount>
  </paymentMethodDetails>
</paymentMethods>
<invoiceDetails>
  <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
  <netValue>36.70</netValue>
  <vatCategory>1</vatCategory>
  <vatAmount>8.80</vatAmount>
  <incomeClassification>
    <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
    <icls:classificationCategory>category1_1</icls:classificationCategory>
    <icls:amount>36.70</icls:amount>
  </incomeClassification>
</invoiceDetails>
<invoiceSummary>
  <totalNetValue>36.70</totalNetValue>
  <totalVatAmount>8.80</totalVatAmount>
  <totalWithheldAmount>0.00</totalWithheldAmount>
  <totalFeesAmount>0.00</totalFeesAmount>
  <totalStampDutyAmount>0.00</totalStampDutyAmount>
  <totalOtherTaxesAmount>0.00</totalOtherTaxesAmount>
  <totalDeductionsAmount>0.00</totalDeductionsAmount>
  <totalGrossValue>45.50</totalGrossValue>
  <incomeClassification>
    <icls:classificationType>E3_561_001</icls:classificationType>
    <icls:classificationCategory>category1_1</icls:classificationCategory>
    <icls:amount>36.70</icls:amount>
  </incomeClassification>
</invoiceSummary>
</invoice>
</InvoicesDoc>
```

Is there a way to change the wizard created unit to produce the correct XML with prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work around to manually add the prefix:

First declare variables for all three entries (here show only the first):

```
nodeClassificationType:IXMLNode;
```

And then replace the code:

```
IncomeClassificationType.ClassificationType:='xxxxxx'
```

with:

```
nodeClassificationType:=
  IncomeClassificationType.AddChild('icls:classificationType');
nodeClassificationType.Text:='xxxxx'
```

This worked perfectly!!